# how to add details in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to add user details in database. I create new username and password then it will go to the details page. In this details page, The details are added to the database. But my Problem is what means the details are not added correctly.

In my controller

My code is

int candidateId;

```
        [HttpPost, HandleErrorWithAjaxFilter]


       public ActionResult Add(FormCollection collection, HttpPostedFileBase resume)
    {
        if (LoggedInCandidate == null)
        {

            Candidate candidate = new Candidate();
            candidate.Name = collection["Name"];
            candidate.Email = collection["Email"];
            candidate.Address = collection["Address"];
            candidate.ContactNumber = collection["ContactNumber"];
            candidate.MobileNumber = collection["MobileNumber"];
            candidate.LicenseNumber = collection["LicenseNumber"];
             int candidateId = _repository.AddCandidate(candidate);
            }
            else
            {
            candidateId = LoggedInCandidate.Id;
            }

                _repository.Save();
```

Here, In database it creates the Id. But the details are not added to the db. It shows null. Can anyone clarify me this one?

Comment: Yes. All the controls are in the same Form only.

Answer (score 0):

All the controls in the same Form Collection or not. if its having in the same formcollection, it must work.

Other way try with Request["Name"]

Comment: Can you please post the formtag html that can helpful to find. Any div tag which is upper in the form tag is closed before the form tag closing it may get the problem